# Java get new number but ignore numbers in front of letters

Tags: java

I am trying to think of a way to resolve my problem. I didn't found the perfect solution I hope someone here can help me out.

So, I have an array of identifier numbers like:
...
3113,
3114,
3115 A1,
3115 A2,
3116
...

I want to return the next number available to insert.
Currently Im using this function but for some reason it dont work I think because it is reading the number 3115 A1 as 31151. 
In this example I want to return 3117.

Here's the function in JAVA:

```
  public String getNewNumber(){
    int lastNumber = 1;
    for(String number : listNumbers){
      if(Integer.parseInt(number.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")) > lastNumber){
        lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
      }
    }
    int newNumber = lastNumber + 1;
    return newNumber + "";
  }
```

Comment: Give us more Context: Do you want the lowest free number or the highest number+1? Is your List ordered? Can it happen that some entries are deleted? If there is a letter, does it always have a preceeding whitespace?

Comment: why do you want 3117?

Comment: Yes, I want to have the highest number +1 and ignore the numbers in front of the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the letters you should extract the number with split, this removes a lot of possible bugs when the string changes. This requires the first number in the string to be the one you want to extract.

```
public String getNewNumber(String[] listNumbers) {
    int lastNumber = 1;
    for (String listNumber : listNumbers) {
        String splitNumber = listNumber.split("\\D")[0];
        int parsedNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitNumber);
        if(parsedNumber > lastNumber) {
            lastNumber = parsedNumber;
        }
    }
    int newNumber = lastNumber + 1;
    return String.valueOf(newNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`number.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")`
It will replace all non-digit number from the string, so `3115 A1` becomes `31151`. So instead of replacing all non digit character from input number, find first non-digit character and take substring.

```
String getNewNumber(String[] listNumbers) {

    int lastNumber = 1;
    for (String number : listNumbers) {
        int index = firstNonDigitIndex(number);
        int numberInt = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, index));
        if (numberInt > lastNumber) {
            lastNumber = numberInt;
        }
    }
    int newNumber = lastNumber + 1;
    return Integer.toString(newNumber);
}

/**
 * Returns index of first non-digit char in string or str.length()
 */
int firstNonDigitIndex(String str) {

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return str.length();
}
```

Also if your input listNumbers is sorted (it seems from your example), so you don't need to iterate all numbers, just parse the last number.